# Bluetooth SPP module SPP-C SPP-CA BK3211 chip - entering AT mode?

Tags: bluetooth, hardware, at-command, spp

I have Bluetooth SPP module SPP-C / SPP-CA , it is cheap module that should work the same way as well known HC-06 / HC-05 modules.

I have got one problem, everything works, module is communicating over serial interface pairing etc... but i can not enter the AT mode to change device name pin or baud rate. Does anyone had the same problem and how to solve it ? there is a very small data published and sellers are not responding.

So I assume that someone may help  with that situation. http://www.ebay.com/itm/Bluetooth-Module-UART-Serial-Interface-SPP-CA-works-with-YZXstudio-USB-Monitors-/201414967094 that's the module. it is based on Beken BK3211 chip.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that nothing special is needed to enter command mode on the SPP-CA module I have.

Whenever you connect or disconnect by bluetooth, the module will print:

```
CONNECTED
.. serial data is transferred ..
+DISC:SUCCESS
```

When the module is disconnected, you can execute AT commands such as `AT+BAUD` just like with HC05 modules.

Answer (score 0):

3 years later and I've looked everywhere for an answer to this question and finally stumbled upon the solution by fiddling away.

I am connecting via an FTDI module using Teraterm software to enter commands.

You need to power up the FTDI and BT modules by plugging into PC USB. open Teraterm and set up to see the COM port.

Now you have to momentarily connect GND to port 11 on the BT module to 'reset' the module. The module will power down and back up again and in doing so will enter AT mode and you should be able to communicate with the module.

Good luck

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Old question however still relevant, I found the solution! It is pretty simple, you can use an breadboard and some jumper wires however you can also create an adapter like I did. Like explained in [this document](https://roboticafacil.es/datasheets/SPP.pdf) with AT-commands, you need another UART (serial connection) to program the SPP. The SPP must not connected to anything (discovery mode) to be able to program it.

You can do this, like I did, with another SPP or you can use serial programmer or an Arduino. Notice that the serial connection is 3V, so when using an Arduino you need some resistors (1K and 2K) to create a voltage divider (google it).

The schematic is pretty simple (when not using an Arduino), I designed this adapter:

[image: SPP-AT-CMD-Adapter]

You need these components to create the adapter (and maybe some wires):

[image: AT-CMD-Adapter-Requirements]

Connect everything like in the schematic above (STATE and EN are not connected), insert the modules (take care of pin orientation!), insert an USB cable and connect it to some power source.

In Arduino IDE, select the com-port you want to configure and launch the Serial monitor, you can now enter AT-commands to configure the one that is not connected:

[image: Serial-monitor-arduino-ide]

Done! That is pretty easy right? When you want to configure the other, disconnect the one that is connect and connect the other one. An overview of AT-commands can be found in the document in provided link above.

Hopes it helps ;-)